# Unexpected Token with service script

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script that manages services on the server and starts/stops etc...depending on the Task in the csv file, as well as changes the startuptype, again depending on the start up type in the csv file.

CSV file:

```
Server,Service,Startup Type,Task
server1,SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER),automatic,start
server2,"SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER), SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER) CEIP",Manual,stop
```

Script

```
$csvFile = Import-CSV .\SSAS_services.csv

$ServiceState = Get-Service -Name
$ServiceStartupType = Get-Service | select -property name,starttype

ForEach ($row in $csvFile)
{   
    #checking if service in csv file exists on server
    if (Get-Service $row.Service | Select-Object Name, StartType, Status -ComputerName $row.Server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
        "$row.Service not found on $row.Server!" | out-file .\SSAS_services.txt -Append
    }
    else 
    {
        Get-Service $row.Service | Select-Object Name, StartType, Status -ComputerName $row.Server | select machinename,name | format-table -AutoSize
    }

    # Change the service on the server

    if ($row.Task -eq "stop" -and $row.Server $ServiceState $row.Service -ne "stop")
    {
        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Stop-Service $using:row.Service } -ComputerName    $row.Server -ArgumentList $row
        Start-Sleep 60
    }
    elseif ($row.Task -eq "start" -and $row.Server $ServiceState $row.Service -ne "start")
    {
        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Start-Service $using:row.Service } -ComputerName    $row.Server -ArgumentList $row
        Start-Sleep 60
    }
    elseif ($row.Task -eq "pause" -and $row.Server $ServiceState $row.Service -ne "pause")
    {
        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Suspend-Service $using:row.Service } -ComputerName    $row.Server -ArgumentList $row
        Start-Sleep 60
    }
    elseif ($row.Task -eq "Restart")
    {
        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Restart-Service $using:row.Service } -ComputerName    $row.Server -ArgumentList $row
        Start-Sleep 60
    }

    #changing startup type if different

    if ($row."Startup Type" -eq $ServiceStartupType -ComputerName    $row.Server)
    {
        "Changing Startup Type from '$ServiceStartupType' to $row.'Startup Type'"

        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Set-Service $using:row.Service -StartupType $using:row."Startup Type" } -ComputerName    $row.Server -ArgumentList $row
    }

} | Tee-object .\SSAS_services.txt -Append
```

I am getting the following errors:

> Unexpected token '$ServiceState' in expression or statement.
>   +     if ($row.Task -eq "stop" -and $row.Server $ServiceState $row.Serv ...
>
> Missing closing ')' after expression in 'if' statement.
>   + ...  if ($row.Task -eq "stop" -and $row.Server $ServiceState $row.Service ...
>
> Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
>   + ... sk -eq "stop" -and $row.Server $ServiceState $row.Service -ne "stop")
>   +
>
> Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
>   + ...  elseif ($row.Task -eq "start" -and $row.Server $ServiceState $row.Se ...
>   ~
>
> Unexpected token '$ServiceState' in expression or statement.
>   +     elseif ($row.Task -eq "start" -and $row.Server $ServiceState $row ...
>   +
>
> Unexpected token '$row' in expression or statement.
>   + ...  -eq "start" -and $row.Server $ServiceState $row.Service -ne "start")
>   +  Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
>   + ...  elseif ($row.Task -eq "pause" -and $row.Server $ServiceState $row.Se ...
>   +
>                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Unexpected token '$ServiceState' in expression or statement. Not all parse errors were reported.  Correct
>   the reported errors and try again.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken                                                  ~

Comment: I'd suggest reading your error messages.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1  I assure you i have. my if statements are not missing their () and {} as it says, and I am not sure whats wrong with the $servicestate variable or $row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if statement with `-and $row.Server $ServiceState $row.Service -ne "stop"` isn't  valid powershell syntax (the expression should evaluate to boolean). You have write a function or use `invoke-expression` to evaluate the service state.

E.g.

```
 $serviceName = "WSearch"
 $command = "get-service $serviceName"
 if ((invoke-expression $command).Status -eq "Running") {
    # do something...
 }
```

Comment: So do I wrap it in ( )?

Comment: There's literally no reason to use `Invoke-Expression` in your example.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 um then what would be the right solution?

Comment: @Peter Schneider someone downvoted you, as well as I apparently. I gave you an upvote to make up for the injustice you have received my friend.